# pytest githook on Windows with Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, git, githooks, anaconda3

I have the following setup:

- Windows 10
- python installed via Anaconda
- Virtual environment setup via Anaconda for running and testing my project with pytest
- git version control via MINGW

Now I'd like to set a githook that runs all my tests before I push. I have the following problem: I can't activate my virtual environment within the githook.

I tried to activate my anaconda env in the githook script but I can't get it to work. `activate` as command is not available and calling the whole path `../Anaconda3/Scripts/activate.bat` does nothing.

I also tried to use python-githooks to configure the hook for me, but this doesn't seem to work in Windows (it can't read `PWD` from the environment...)

I'm gratefull for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a .bat-File at the root of the git repository, with:

`call C:\...\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call activate fs_env
pytest`

and to call this file within the pre-push file in .git/hooks with:

`./runtests.bat`